# Enable php to execute .php files that start with just <?

Tags: ubuntu, php

I bought a php script on Code canyon, and it was running ok on my localhosts (Xampp), but when i uploaded the files to my server, I noticed that the `.php` files where not being executed, after some investigation I discovered that my server does not recognise the php files, because they start with just `<?`, instead of `<?php`.

Is it possible to change PHP to execute `.php` files that start with just `<?`

I running ubuntu 14.04, with php 5.5.9

Comment: FWIW: please note that configuring `php` to parse files with only `<?` will make it difficult for you to make an XML declaration e.g.: `<?xml version="1.0"?>`. It is frequently a deprecated practice, but opinions vary. See: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php

Comment: Thanks Eric, after reading a little about, i enable the short_open_tag, via htaccess only in the directory i was using the .php files.

Comment: Good compromise. I once inherited a site that used the short tag exclusively. Ended up with a `find` `sed` hack to rewrite every file; so we could remove the feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change PHP's .ini file to include this (or change existing definition):

```
short_open_tag=1
```